# How to execute .exe in batch file with additional commands?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe

I am trying to write a small `.bat` file that changes the directory and executes, which this uploads the `default.bin` to my keyboard for a layout change:

```bat
mdloader_windows.exe --first --download default.bin --restart
```

- I don't know how to get the `.bin` part below to work *(maybe the whole line has to be executed as once?)*, and so far I've got:

  ```bat
  @echo off
  pause>nul
  cd /d "G:\Downloads\keyboard prog"
  start "mdloader_windows.exe"
  ```

How do I get this to work?

- This should work fine, but `mloader_windows.exe` still won't start:

  ```bat
  @echo off
  cd /d "G:\Downloads\keyboard prog"
  start mdloader_windows.exe
  --first
  --download default.bin
  --restart

  cmd /k
  ```

  - I tried this with another `.exe` and it works, but since `mloader_windows.exe` is an `.exe` that opens in cmd, having the other commands as menu items, what do I have to do differently? I can run it manually no problem, but how to get it to start automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the syntax of the [start command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html):

```bat
start "" "G:\Downloads\keyboard prog\mdloader_windows.exe" --first --download default.bin --restart
```

Comment: doesn't work unfortunately, for more details see the comment on the other post below.

Comment: Try to use the full path for  mdloader. If it contains blanks enclose in quotes.

Comment: i found out that the mdloader.exe doesn't start. Probably because it's .exe that runs in cmd itself. The commands after that are menu points of the program. When i put in a standard install .exe it works. Also when i just type it in manually it works aswell. Any idea how to start a specific .exe like that?

Comment: Try the command in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply by adding the parameter after the program

```
@echo off
pause>nul
cd /d "G:\Downloads\keyboard prog"
start mdloader_windows.exe --first --download default.bin --restart
```

but this should also work without the start command

```
mdloader_windows.exe --first --download default.bin --restart
```

Comment: i tried that before but that didnt seem to work. Therefore i thought i had to split the commands up in single lines which also didnt do what i wanted. Normally i would open cmd in the keyboard prog folder and copy the complete mdloader line in. This starts loading in my .bin file and gives me a 60 second timer to press the reset button on my keyboard, to change my layout. When i do it like you suggested, nothing seems to happen.